# Need help using Newsoft.Json on VB.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to use Newtonsoft.Json and can't use it.

I installed it by NuGet, but if I put "using Newtonsoft.Json" it says that Newtonsoft.Json is a namespace and can't be used as an expression.
Thank you.

```
Using Newtonsoft.Json;
  JObject channel = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\stats.json"));
  channel["points"] = ((number)channel["points"]) += score;
  channel["name"] = ((string)channel["name"]) = name;
End Using
```

Here's the JSON:

```
{
      'stats': {
      'points': 0,
      'name': 'John Doe'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems to be c# (uses ;). Are you sure about vb.net?

Comment: Yes. The markdown messed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that VB.NET `Using` statements are used with Objects that have a dedicated `Dispose()` method, not namespaces.
An example of this would be:

```vb
Using DisposableObject As New Object
    DisposableObject.Method1()
End Using
```

In order to use the namespace, all you need to do is include the Newtonsoft library in your `Imports` statement, like so:

```vb
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

And you can use it anywhere within the module.

If you want access to the entire Newtonsoft library, just add `Imports Newtonsoft`

EDIT for C#:

In C# it's much the same but instead of `Imports` put `using`. There is no need for an `end using`:

```
using Newtonsoft.JSON;
// Place this at the top of your code and ensure the Newtonsoft dll is in the folder with your built app
```

You also have the minor issue of incorrect C# syntax:

```
using (DisposableObject x = new DisposableObject) {
    x.Method1();
}
```

Hope that helped

Comment: Still can't use it. I'm trying to use the JSON on a method. PS: Yes, i put the Imports on the first line.

Comment: The tag VB.NET was wrong. I have changed it to C#. So the answer is probably not relevant.

Comment: C# doesn't have `end` statements, and the tag was VB.NET (haha). I've edited my answer to fix the `using` syntax, but if that doesn't fix it then it might be a problem with the Newtonsoft library, which I'm not as experienced with